# Converting row data using pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server

My Table Format is

```
    TableName       columnName              IssueType       IssueDetails    
tblOrder_Inv    OrderI_mnySalesTax1     DefaultValue    MSSQL=NULL|MySql=0.0000
tblOrder_Inv    OrderI_mnySalesTax1     DataType        MSSQL=NULL|MySql=0.0000    
tblOrder_Inv    OrderI_dtmDateTime      IsNullable      MSSQL=NULL|MySql=0.0000
tblOrder_Inv    OrderI_dtmDateTime      DefaultValue    MSSQL=NULL|MySql=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP    
tblOrder_Inv    OrderI_mnyInvTotal      DefaultValue    MSSQL=NULL|MySql=0.0000
```

I need in this format

```
TableName       columnName              DefaultValue    IsNullable  DataType    
tblOrder_Inv    OrderI_mnySalesTax1     Yes             No          Yes    
tblOrder_Inv    OrderI_dtmDateTime      Yes             Yes         No    
tblOrder_Inv    OrderI_mnyInvTotal      Yes             No          NO
```

Data flows is Each table has many columns and each column has different issues
(DefaultValue DataType IsNullable). Each column with one issue is inserted as one row.

So for instance tableA => ColumnA => has two issues say IsNullable, DefaultValue
is inserted as

```
tableA  ColumnA IsNullable
tableA  ColumnA DefaultValue
```

as two rows.

I need this to be like dis

```
tableA ColumnA Isnullable DefaultValue
```

likewise ..

if the same tableA has ColumnB with any issueType should be getting as a new row.

I tried Pivot

`select * from ( select TableName,columnName, IssueType from #tmp) AS T
pivot (MAX(columnName) For IssueType In (DefaultValue,DataType,IsNullable)) as T2`

Not getting the desired result. Is it possible to achieve this by pivot?

Please help me..

**UPDATE :**

In addition to that can i get concatination of IssueDetails columns as well in final query in the accepted answer ?

Comment: Yes, [it is possible using PIVOT](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/14105/1), but I don't think it adds anything the accepted answer.

Comment: @GarethD yup right. Curious to know my mistake in that pivot which i tried.. fine let me search on that just to know :)
cheers !!

Comment: You don't have any columns with `YES/NO` in, so you can't expect these in the result of the PIVOT, instead you need to create a column with `YES` in for rows that exist, then where the row doesn't exist (i.e. the result is `NULL`) use `NO`. In your pivot since you use `columnname` in the aggregate, it does not include it in the implied group by.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

result of:

```
|    TABLENAME |          COLUMNNAME | DEFAULTVALUE | ISNULLABLE | DATATYPE |
|--------------|---------------------|--------------|------------|----------|
| tblOrder_Inv |  OrderI_dtmDateTime |          Yes |        Yes |       No |
| tblOrder_Inv |  OrderI_mnyInvTotal |          Yes |         No |       No |
| tblOrder_Inv | OrderI_mnySalesTax1 |          Yes |         No |      Yes |
```

produced by:

```
   SELECT
          TableName
        , columnName
        , MAX(CASE
                WHEN IssueType = 'DefaultValue' THEN 'Yes'
                ELSE 'No' END) as DefaultValue
        , MAX(CASE
                WHEN IssueType = 'IsNullable' THEN 'Yes'
                ELSE 'No' END) as IsNullable
        , MAX(CASE
                WHEN IssueType = 'DataType' THEN 'Yes'
                ELSE 'No' END) as DataType
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY
          TableName
        , columnName
```

Before "pivot" become a SQL instruction using case expressions like this was referred to as pivoting, and they are still very useful for this purpose.

see: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b5de2/3

Comment: +1 sneaky albeit somewhat hacky use of MAX there. Just don't localize the Yes/No strings :)

Comment: Thank you much man.. Exactly what expected .. !!!!
The result is exact what i need..

Comment: The query will generate multiple rows with results, however if one row says 'Yes', MAX() for that column will return 'Yes' since the string 'Yes' is greater than the string 'No'. In swedish for example, Yes/No is Ja/Nej, which would break the logic if the query s localised since 'Nej'>'Ja' instead of the other way around.

Comment: There is really only one possible value for `DefaultValue` in the data or it not present. If `DefaultValue` is present you get Yes if not you get No. MAX() just ensures you get the highest value where Yes is higher then No. Point is you have to use an aggregate function in those locations otherwise you cannot reduce the number of rows to one per table+field.

Comment: You could return 1 (yes), 0 (no) instead, then use an I18N lookup table to translate into local yes/no strings

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson this is not sneaky or a hack. The technique described here is referred to as a cross tab. This a well known technique that has been in use for a LONG time. In fact, a cross tab will outperform a pivot nearly every time. They have the additional advantage that they are easier to read and understand. Also, they can support multiple aggregates which a PIVOT can't.

Comment: @SeanLange I wasn't referring to the technique itself, I was referring to using `MAX()` to build functionality on the sort ordering of strings, something that may very well not work in another locale. The technique is very easy to convert to not use the string comparison part dependency but the answer is already accepted. I may add a version once I get to a computer instead of my iPhone ;)

Comment: Joachim the need for I18N is recognized, and an appropriate response could be to use lookups to translate an enumerated value to a language based label. Personally I think this is outside the scope of the question